# How do I determine which crypto library application uses?

Tags: ssl, windows, openssl, diffie-hellman

Is there any method to do so? I have access to the application's assembly in Ghidra as well as app's TLS 1.2 traffic in Wireshark.

I used Ghidra and found some data about OpenSSL 1.0.2l, but breakpoints on `int SSL_connect(SSL *s)` function don't get hit, so I guess it isn't used anymore/yet.

Comment: Do you want to know the *library* or the *algorithm*?

Comment: @schroeder I want to know the library. With that knowledge, I'm planning to extract ssl keys needed to decrypt the SSL traffic

Comment: Is it possible to determine any type of library used by a compiled binary? I'm not sure there is.

Comment: @schroeder how about wireshark traffic dump? is there anything potentially useful?

Comment: How will the packets tell you the programming library used by a binary? that's several levels of abstraction away from each other.

Comment: @schroeder ok, so how about unique library strings inside the binary? do you know any except openssl?

Comment: Then you would have to know what is unique per library and hope you can find those strings.

Comment: @schroeder btw. do you think it's possible that the application DOES use openssl and DOESN'T use `int SSL_connect(SSL *s)` function? Is it even possible?

Comment: If it's a dynamically linked binary, you may be able to see the name of the library that it needs

Comment: @multithr3at3d unfortunately for me it's statically linked